# Does AES_ENCRYPT reduce the byte size of the encrypted text?

Tags: mysql, sql, aes

I know that `base64` increases the total 'size' of the specific image or text by 1/3, but what about `AES_ENCRYPT`?

Comment: I think it adds some bytes, but it's not a % like with base64. I use AES for files and I don't even notice the difference.

Comment: Base64 is an ASCII-safe *encoding* for binary data, used to ensure data isn't lost in transmission over binary-unsafe medium. It makes no attempt to conceal the data. AES on the other hand is a symmetric block cipher, ie: it does *encryption*. These are two totally different concepts (encoding vs encryption). This is an apples to bottles comparison. cc @ChocoDeveloper

Comment: @NullUserException Nobody said any different, though I see how a beginner could get confused by this. Anyway, the term encoding does not necessarily imply that it's not encryption. Eg: many libraries use 'encode()' as the name of the encryption function.

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper Those libraries make a great disservice to everyone by helping perpetuate misconceptions. According to the Oxford dictionary, [encode](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/encode) in Computing means *"convert (information or an instruction) into a particular form."* Compare that to the definition of [encrypt](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/encrypt), which includes the intent of hiding this information.

Comment: @NullUserException I'm still not convinced. Encryption does transform the data if you ask me. And there are just too many places where it is used like that. Eg: "break the code", or "Da Vinci Code". The information is encoded, whether it makes sense in its current form is a different matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AES is a block cipher and thus processes data only in multiples of a specified block size. Its input (and as a result is output) is padded with enough bytes to round the size up towards a multiple of the block size. Since the manual [says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt) that an 128-bit key is used, we know the block size is 16 bytes.

The manual also gives a formula that describes this mathematically:

> the result string length may be calculated using this formula:
>
> ```
> 16 * (trunc(string_length / 16) + 1)
> ```